# Can I manipulate the popup.html DOM with bundled Javascript file when its rendered?

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-chrome-extension, popup

I am building a chrome-extension. I have a .js file which gets bundled with `webpack`, I am also using node modules in this file, it manages my executions, etc.

I want to reach `popup.html`'s DOM when it is revoked and manipulate it before rendering. I will add event listeners to buttons in my `popup.html`.

I can't add these event listeners in `popup.js` because I need to use node packages in the listener which I can't import in `popup.js`.

I tried to import node modules in `popup.js`, which didn't work because it doesn't get bundled. When I bundle it, it doesn't get revoked by `popup.html` call.

Comment: The popup code runs each time the popup is shown, it doesn't run when the popup is hidden, so it's unclear what do you mean by "when it is revoked". You need to put the code that modifies the popup's DOM in some of the scripts that are loaded by popup.html, there's no other way.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Can I bundle that script which is loaded by `popup.html` and load the bundled version of it? So, I can use `require` or `import`?

Comment: I'm not aware of the specifics with bundling you mentioned. As for `require`, browsers don't have it so you need to have a script that defines this function. As for `import`, you can use ES-imports just like you would use it anywhere else.

Comment: ![Error Image](https://i.ibb.co/28qBtMJ/extension.png) as you can see here I can't use `import`. Also, I mentioned the bundle as webpack bundling.

Comment: To use ES-imports you need to declare the type of the script in your html, see the documentation.

Comment: I worked around this problem by sending a message to my content script on specific events, and receiving them on the content script side and evaluating as needed.

Yet, it is not the answer to the problem above, it is just a workaround.

Comment: Also, importing the script with `type="module"` and bundling the `popup.js` script then importing bundled version didn't help.